# How to make a span with glyphicon as a hyperlink?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some form with `glyphicon` question mark for field inline **tooltip** on right:

```
<div class="form-group required">
    <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3 tooltip-box">
        <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username"/>
        <div class="row tooltip-block"><a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="auto right" data-content="Test tooltip.">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In full screen it looks as I need:

[image]

But on mobile devices or small screens it works only with hovering **some very small area** within my glyphicon mark and the tooltip overlays it:

[image]

Also when I inspect the corresponding `a` element in Chrome's developer tools, it points to some area outside the `span` element:

[image]

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r2cm9c9u/

How is it possible to make the whole `span` with glyphicon as a hyperlink for tooltip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would move the positioning to the actual link and make the link and glyphicon a block element:

I have added a class to the link below

```html
<div class="form-group required">
  <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Name:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3 tooltip-box">
    <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" />
    <div class="row tooltip-block">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="auto right" data-content="Test tooltip." class="glyphicon-holder">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And changed your classes:

```css
.tooltip-box .glyphicon-holder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 22px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  display: block;
}

.tooltip-box .glyphicon-holder:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.glyphicon.glyphicon-question-sign {
  color: gray;
  display: block;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2cm9c9u/1/)

Comment: By the way, don't you know how to remove the glyphicon underlining on hover? As https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4a7v.png

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with pure css.

If you have:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 tooltip-box">
        <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username"/>
        <div class="row tooltip-block"><a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="auto right" data-content="Test tooltip.">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You don't need 'a' first of all. What you can do with CSS is:

```
.tooltip-block span {
    display: none;
}

.tooltip-block:hover + span {
    display: block;
}
```

Whats gonna happen is, when you hover over .tooltip-block following span element will display block. Definitely don't need javascript for a thing like this.

Then if you want that tooltip to be clickable you can use javascript for that.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 tooltip-box">
            <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username"/>
            <div class="row tooltip-block" onclick="doSomething()"><a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="auto right" data-content="Test tooltip.">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Nice idea, thanks. Although I'm not able to run it without JavaScript, I'll think about your idea.